# Redux initial state values becomes undefined

Tags: redux, state

Below is my initial default state values,

```
export const parameterInitialState = {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    parameterSettings: parameterSettingsInitialState,
    parameterMediaSettings: parameterMediaSettingsInitialState,
};

export const parameterSettingsInitialState = {
    attributeId: '',
    value: '',
};

export const parameterMediaSettingsInitialState = {
    barcodeSupported: false,
    mediaTypeId: '',
    qrcodeSupported: false,
    scratchOffPINSupported: false,
};
```

in the parameterState reducer, I use the above parameterInitialState

```
const initialState = {
    parameterSettings: parameterInitialState,
};

export default function parameterState( state = initialState, action ) {
    switch ( action.type ) {
        case FETCH_PARAMETER_SUCCESS:{
            return { ...state,  ...action.payload };
        }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

But my issue is in the initial state the object parameterSettings and parameterMediaSettings becomes undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order in which your initial state variables are defined, in the given order variables `parameterSettingsInitialState` and `parameterMediaSettingsInitialState` will return undefined.

So make sure the child object variables are defined first followed by the parent object you plan include them in.

```
    export const parameterSettingsInitialState = {
        attributeId: '',
        value: '',
    };

    export const parameterMediaSettingsInitialState = {
        barcodeSupported: false,
        mediaTypeId: '',
        qrcodeSupported: false,
        scratchOffPINSupported: false,
    };

    export const parameterInitialState = {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        parameterSettings: parameterSettingsInitialState,
        parameterMediaSettings: parameterMediaSettingsInitialState,
    };
```

Updated answer with`parameterSettingsInitialState` and `parameterMediaSettingsInitialState` as arrays :

```
    export const parameterSettingsInitialState = [{
        attributeId: '',
        value: '',
    }];

    export const parameterMediaSettingsInitialState = [{
        barcodeSupported: false,
        mediaTypeId: '',
        qrcodeSupported: false,
        scratchOffPINSupported: false,
    }];

    export const parameterInitialState = {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        parameterSettings: parameterSettingsInitialState,
        parameterMediaSettings: parameterMediaSettingsInitialState,
    };
```

Comment: Thank you, it did work, I want to get the parameterSettingsInitialState as the first element in an array list. in simple words the parameterSettings should be an array with the type of parameterSettingsInitialState.
How can I do that

Comment: @Anna you're welcome. If I understand you correctly, changing `parameterSettingsInitialState` definition from type object to type array like so should do the trick.  

`const parameterSettingsInitialState = [{
    attributeId: '',
    value: '',
}];`

Comment: Hi @Anna if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.

Comment: I tried with 
`export const parameterInitialState = {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        parameterSettings: [ {parameterSettingsInitialState} ],
        parameterMediaSettings: [ {parameterMediaSettingsInitialState} ],
    };`
but it didnt work